# How can i send an query from java to lpsolve as String

Tags: java, linear-programming, lpsolve

Hi i formulated a linear programing problem using java

and i want to send it to be solved by lpsolve without the need to create each constraint seperatlly.

i want to send the entire block (which if i insert it to the ide works well) and get a result

so basically instead of using something like

```
problem.strAddConstraint("", LpSolve.EQ, 9);
problem.strAddConstraint("", LpSolve.LE, 5);
```

i want to just send as one string

```
min: 0*x11 + 0*x12 + 0*x13

x11 + x12 + x13= 9;
x12 + x12<5;
```

can it be done if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LpSolve supports LP files as well as MPS files. Everything is thoroughly detailed in the API documentation (see http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/).

You can do your job like this in java :

```
lp = LpSolve.readLP("model.lp", NORMAL, "test model");
LpSolve.solve(lp)
```

What is sad with file based approaches is that you will not be able to use warm start features. I would not suggest you to use such approach if you want to optimize successive similar problems.

Cheers